# Using ServiceStack and RabbitMQ to send messages from one queue to another

Tags: servicestack, rabbitmq

I have ServiceStack service **registered as a message queue handler**.   While the service is handling a message and an error is encountered I would like to pull the remaining messages from the queue and send them to a different queue.  Here is the code I am trying to use.

```
if (error)
{
    using (var mqClient = TryResolve<IMessageFactory>().CreateMessageQueueClient())
    {
        var callMessage = mqClient.Get<CallMessage>(QueueNames<CallMessage>.In);
        while (callMessage != null)
        {
        mqClient.Ack(callMessage);
        PublishMessage(new TextMessage { Text = callMessage.Text });

        // Get the next message. Null is returned when the queue is empty
        callMessage = mqClient.Get<CallMessage>(QueueNames<CallMessage>.In);
        }
    }
}
```

However, upon calling mqClient.Get the CallMessage queue seems to get deadlocked with an active Unacked message.

[image]

What is the proper technique for pulling messages from a queue and republishing them to a different queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to instead use `IMessageQueueClient.GetAsync` to retrieve a message from a queue, which will either return the next message or `null` if there are no more messages pending.

`IMessageQueueClient.Get` is a synchronous blocking Get that will block until it receives a message or the optional timeout has elapsed, if no timeout is given it will block forever until it receives a message.

Comment: Thank you, @mythz using GetAsync resolved the problem with Get blocking, but it always returns null. I have found that all the messages in the queue have already been dequeued in the 'Unacked' state in RabbitMq, so the null result makes sense.  Does ServiceStack dequeue the messages as a batch?  I am  registering the handler using "mqServer.RegisterHandler<CallMessage>(ServiceController.ExecuteMessage);"

Comment: @jacksonakj it only pulls it out 1 at a time from the underlying C# RabbitMQ client, but it does specify a [prefetchCount of 20](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.RabbitMq/RabbitMqProducer.cs#L40) on the underlying channel.